# How can i find this pattern in file using linux shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

```
string Xh,Xh,Xh,Xh;
```

Here X can be any Hex number(upto 4 digit).
What i want to find is string followed by 4 numbers separated by comma and ended with semicolon.

Sample input:

```
READ 1h, 2h, 3h, 4h;
```

Here READ is a string.

Comment: can you give some sample  input?

Answer (score -1):

You may find it using grep:

```
echo "string aFh, 09h, 4bh, FFh;" | grep -e "string \([a-fA-F0-9]\{2\}h\, \)\{3\}\([a-fA-F0-9]\{2\}h\;\)"
```

Answer (score -1):

The below grep command will work as you expected.

grep -E "^([A-Za-z]+[0-9]{4}),([A-Za-z]+[0-9]{4}),([A-Za-z]+[0-9]{4}),([A-Za-z]+[0-9]{4})\;$"

It will match the string followed by 4 digits(without space between string and digit) and match the comma, up to 4 times like this and ended with semicolon line.